# Can't click Allow External Write Access Permissions in Android

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-external-storage

I'm not able to allow the app to write to external storage when other background app like twilight (dims screen) runs in the background. In this case, I can only deny it and it says screen overlay detected. But can't allow.

My code:

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        boolean hasPermission = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Timetable.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        if (!hasPermission) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Timetable.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    1);
        }
    }
```

Override code:

```
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                //Intent i=new Intent(this,Timetable.class);
                //startActivity(i);
                //reload my activity with permission granted or use the features what required the permission
            } else
            {
                Toast.makeText(Timetable.this, "The app was not allowed to write to your storage. Hence, it cannot function properly. Please consider granting it this permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I want it running even if some background apps like twilight are running.

Comment: Can you add screenshots / logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading a certain file using Android's built in Download Manager provides integrity and a more User Friendly approach. Also the requestPermission method should be called before doing that if the devices having Marshmallow and above are to be supported as well.

And about the allow button not working, that issue is because of apps or activities who capture the screen overlay. Like for instance Facebook messenger or any screen dimming apps. Hence to make it robust you need to check the permission everytime you download something.

```
public void downloadFile(String uRl) {
    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/" + "MyFolder");

    if (!direct.exists()) {
        direct.mkdirs();
    }

    DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(this.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uRl);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);

    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
            DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                    | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
            .setTitle("AppNameAsTitle")
            .setDescription("Downloaded using My app")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/MyFolder", "filename.jpg")
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    mgr.enqueue(request);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        downloadFile(url);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much SanVed for helping me out! Hope, Android will fix the screen overlay soon. Download Manager part is best!